# Array type not declared during file parsing JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to output the split contents of a `.txt` file.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class PassFail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "C:\\new_java\\Final_Project\\src\\student.txt";

        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

            String line = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            String[] values = line.split(" ");

            int nums[] = new int[values.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
                nums[x] = Integer.parseInt(values[x]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e);
        }

        System.out.println(nums[1]);

    }

}
```

**Question:** Why am I getting the error "`nums cannot be resolved to a variable`" when trying to output `num[2]`? Furthermore, how can I fix this? To my knowledge I have already declared `nums[]` as a an int data type just before the `for` loop.

Comment: I indented your code for you. Now take a look at scope of `nums`. Can we access variables declared in inner code block from outer code block?

Answer (score 2):

Because `nums` is defined in the try block, and you try to access it outside the try.

Also, it's nicer if you use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse. This will help you format the code, and more easily spot errors like this.

Comment: Well that was a simple solution. I seriously couldn't find it online though, so thank you!

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse Galileo. lol.

Comment: @RobertTossly Then spam `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` or `Ctrl`+`I` whenever you can.

Comment: It helps if you know what to search on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655020/why-does-a-try-catch-block-create-new-variable-scope. Also, press CTRL + SHIFT + F. It helps ;-)

Comment: Man, that is crazy, I wish I knew how to format before posting this. Also, I'd hate to ask a question in the comments, but my teacher wants us to add exception handling. Is it possible to add exception handling in this code without messing up the scope?

Comment: It's better to ask a new question and state exactly what you are looking for. "Messing up the scope" is a little too non-technical for me :)

Comment: I will do that now :)