# how to create JSONArray of JSONObject from json string?

Tags: java, json

I have a properly formatted json array in a Java string, according to [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/).  No matter what I try, the resulting JSONArray cadDims is empty.  No exceptions reported.  Here is attempt 1 code:

```
String dataStr = "[{\"DIMNAME\":\"d11\",\"DIMID\":\"11\"},{\"DIMNAME\":\"d12\",\"DIMID\":\"12\"}]";
try {
    JSONArray cadDims = new JSONArray(dataStr);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EnCad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Here is attempt 2:

```
String dataStr = "{\"dataStr\":[{\"DIMNAME\":\"d11\",\"DIMID\":\"11\"},{\"DIMNAME\":\"d12\",\"DIMID\":\"12\"}]}";
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(dataStr);
    JSONArray cadDims = obj.getJSONArray("dataStr");
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EnCad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Here is attempt 3:

```
dataStr = "[{\"DIMNAME\": \"d11\",\"DIMID\": 11}, {\"DIMNAME\": \"d12\",\"DIMID\": 12}]";
try {
    JSONArray cadDims = (JSONArray)new JSONTokener(dataStr).nextValue();
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EnCad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Where do you see that it's empty? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I made it as small as I could, other than removing the catch block.  I can see its empty in debugging mode with a breakpoint  after cadDims = ...

Comment: It's minimal, but not complete or verifiable. Please give us something we can reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're doing wrong based on your comments. You need to declare `cadDims` outside of the try catch block, and then initialize the value inside of the try catch block, like this:

```
dataStr = "[{\"DIMNAME\": \"d11\",\"DIMID\": 11}, {\"DIMNAME\": \"d12\",\"DIMID\": 12}]";
JSONArray cadDims;
try {
    cadDims = new JSONArray(dataStr);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EnCad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
if(cadDims != null){
    //Do something with cadDims
}
```

If a variable is declared and initialized inside of a try catch block, it will no longer be accessible outside of that try catch block. I suggest reading up on try catch block scopes and scopes in general to understand this behavior. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11655020/8972283).

Comment: Thank you Francis!  Works now.  Geez, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @user3217883 Why did you say the resulting array was empty and there were no errors?

Comment: I could see it was empty in NetBeans debugging mode with a breakpoint after cadDims.  It was in fact working but by the time I could study cadDims with the debugger, it was outside of the try block, out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
JSONArray cadDims = null;

    String dataStr = "[{\"DIMNAME\":\"d11\",\"DIMID\":\"11\"},{\"DIMNAME\":\"d12\",\"DIMID\":\"12\"}]";

    try {
        cadDims = new JSONArray(dataStr);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EnCad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```